# Unable to open CD

Tags: installation, cd

I have just moved from Windows to Ubuntu. Before I uninstalled windows I put some documents that I needed on a CD. Once I had installed Ubuntu I put the CD in to get the files back. But all I get is the message...

```
Error mounting /dev/sr0 at /media/chris/UDF Volume: Command-line `mount -t "udf" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,umask=0077" "/dev/sr0" "/media/chris/UDF Volume"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

People are not going to migrate from windows if Ubuntu can't even do a simple task like open a CD without this meaningless error message.

Comment: Well as the error suggests, sometimes usefull info is found in the syslog. Can you open a terminal and post the output of: `dmesg | tail` here?

Answer (score 2):

Here is something you can try:

code:

```
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

then add this code after the last line in fstab

code:

```
/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom0 udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8 0 0
```

Comment: tried but I get another error

    Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1:
    helper failed with:
mount: mount point /media/cdrom0 does not exist

Comment: /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8 0 0

Answer (score 0):

try to make /media folder writable by

```
sudo chmod 777 /media
```

Answer (score 0):

/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8 0 0

worked like magic as I had already existing /media/cdrom
created by sudo mkdir /media/cdrom