# Failed to mount UDF

Tags: mount, 14.04, dvd, cd, udf

I'm on Xubuntu 64 bit 14.04. When I had windows 7, I burnt a CD, it was like 4 months ago, now I need to open that CD in Xubuntu, since I no longer have windows.

[image]

[**Solution 1** (didn't work)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1388447)

`sudo apt-get install libudf0`

[**Solution 2** (didn't work)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260316/unable-to-open-cd)

`sudo chmod 777 /media`

**PS:** I won't try **ashish**'s solution unless someone confirms that it will work because **mojo706** said that it didn't work.

[**Solution 3** (didn't work)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359264/how-to-open-udf-volume)

```
▶ sudo mount -t udf /dev/sr0 /cdrom
mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: /dev/sr0: can't read superblock
```

[dmesg output](http://pastebin.com/YxEEiRuK)

Comment: Looks like the disc may be no good.  Check `dmesg` for more details.

Comment: @psusi I included that in my answer

Comment: Can you mount other dvds in that drive?  Either the disc or the drive seems to be broken.

Comment: @psusi yes many  CDs/DVDs work but I don't know if they are in UDF format or not, I've seen the UDF error a couple times

Comment: I'll try it on my brother's windows 7 laptop and update the  question

Comment: Often  `mount` will auto-detect the type, I'd try it without the `-t type` flag. And I wonder if `fdisk -l` or `parted -l` or `gparted` or `blkid` would tell you what the filesystem type is

Answer (score 3):

I got this and could manually mount the disc
as iso9660 instead of udf. I think a recent update
in Ubuntu must have change the default for dvd media

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /mnt
```