# Can't read superblock- UDF DVD

Tags: mount, dvd, udf

I'm having trouble mounting my UDF-formated DVD. It used to work when mounted as a `read-only device` but suddenly one day the system was unable to mount the DVD.

[image: error snapshot]

I searched everywhere I could on Google, but either nothing worked or was not related to my problem. (I also tried mounting the disk as other filesystems but nothing worked).

[Failed to mount UDF](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452332/failed-to-mount-udf#) -I found this thread, but nothing helped.

I am totally at a loss.

Comment: Check `dmesg` or /var/log/syslog for more detailed error messages.